# Pyspark sql count returns different number of rows than pure sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've started using pyspark in one of my projects. I was testing different commands to explore functionalities of the library and I found something that I don't understand.

Take this code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import Dataframe

sc = SparkContext(sc)
hc = HiveContext(sc)

hc.sql("use test_schema")
hc.table("diamonds").count()
```

the last *count()* operation returns 53941 records. If I run instead a *select count(*) from diamonds* in Hive I got 53940.

Is that pyspark count including the header?

I've tried to look into:

```
df = hc.sql("select * from diamonds").collect()
df[0]
df[1]
```

to see if header was included:

```
df[0] --> Row(carat=None, cut='cut', color='color', clarity='clarity', depth=None, table=None, price=None, x=None, y=None, z=None)
df[1] -- > Row(carat=0.23, cut='Ideal', color='E', clarity='SI2', depth=61.5, table=55, price=326, x=3.95, y=3.98, z=2.43)
```

The 0th element doesn't look like the header.

Anyone has an explanation for this?

Thanks!
Ale

Comment: What results do you get when you use `hc.read.table(...).count()`?

Comment: @Bala  when I run that I got 53941

Comment: I tested it with 1.6 and all of them returns same count.  What version are you using?  Create 2 df that gives you different count and do `substract` from one another do get the differing row and let us know.

Comment: I've tried different combination of count operations `hc.sql("select count(*) from diamonds").show()` `hc.read.table().count()` `hc.table(...).count()`, all returning 53491. 

Spark version is 2.1.0, pyspark 2.1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hive can give incorrect counts when stale statistics are used to speed up calculations. To see if this is the problem, in Hive try:

```
SET hive.compute.query.using.stats=false;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM diamonds;
```

Alternatively, refresh the statistics. If your table is not partitioned:

```
ANALYZE TABLE diamonds COMPUTE STATISTICS;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM diamonds;
```

If it is partitioned:

```
ANALYZE TABLE diamonds PARTITION(partition_column) COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

Also take another look at your first row (`df[0]` in your question). It does look like an improperly formatted header row.

Comment: @savagedata you were right, that helps understanding why hive miscount the number of rows. thanks!