# Why is row count different when using spark.table().count() and df.count()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use Spark to read data stored in a very large table (contains `181,843,820` rows and `50` columns) which is my training set, however, when I use `spark.table()` I noticed that the row count is different than the row count when calling the DataFrame's `count()`, I am currently using PyCharm.

I want to preprocess the data in the table before I can use it further as a training set for a model I need to train.
When loading the table I found out that the DataFrame I'm loading the table to is much smaller (10% of the data in this case).

what I have tried:

> 1. raised `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max` capacity.
> 2. load a smaller table into the DataFrame (70k rows) and actually found no difference in the `count()` outputs.

this sample is very similar to the code I ran in order to investigate the problem.

```py
df = spark.table('myTable')
print(spark.table('myTable').count()) # output: 181,843,820
print(df.count()) # output 18,261,961
```

I expect both outputs to be the same (the original 181m), yet they are not, and I dont understand why.

Comment: try to write them down, both of them, and compare the output.

Comment: I cant, the best I can do is to run a SELECT query on the hive, but than again, I cant compare them via the hive.
also I cannot get print the output since I cant get the full content of the original table (too big and also its part of my question, I cant get it into a Dataframe)

Comment: Don’t know if this will solve your problem, but this stackoverflow looks like it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639592/pyspark-sql-count-returns-different-number-of-rows-than-pure-sql